# How can I best sanitize this table?

Tags: r

I did some webscraping and have now a large data frame with 30.000 values that look like this:

```
1 | January 16, 2017
2 |        President Obama announces something
3 |        Today President Obama announced that...
4 | January 17, 2017
5 |        Press Briefing January 17th
6 |        In todays briefing, the press secr...
```

[Screenshot of Data Frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SIO0D.png)

It's always "Date", "Title" and "Content". I've been stuck attempting to sanitize this data for hours now. I would like to convert the text date into machine readable dates and create three seperate columns, one for the date, one for the title and one for the text content so it's all neat and tidy. 
What's the best way to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally, you should fix this while web-scraping itself. However, if there is no way you can go back to fix that and as you have mentioned that the table is always in the form "Date", "Title" and "Content" we can use vector recycling to select rows.

```
df_out <- data.frame(Date = df$V1[c(TRUE, FALSE, FALSE)], 
                     Title = df$V1[c(FALSE, TRUE, FALSE)], 
                     Content = df$V1[c(FALSE, FALSE, TRUE)], 
                      stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
df_out
#               Date                                       Title                                      Content
#1  January 16, 2017         President Obama announces something         Today President Obama announced that
#2  January 17, 2017                 Press Briefing January 17th           In todays briefing, the press secr
```

---

Another option using `dplyr` and `pivot_wider` from `tidyr`

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(V2 = rep(c('Date', 'Title', 'Content'), length.out = n()), 
         row = rep(seq_len(n()), each  =3, length.out = n())) %>%
  tidyr::pivot_wider(names_from = V2, values_from = V1) %>%
  select(-row)
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(V1 = c("January 16, 2017", "President Obama announces something", 
"Today President Obama announced that", "January 17, 2017", "Press Briefing January 17th", 
"In todays briefing, the press secr")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```